How do I load MySQL dump file?
I'm using MySQL Server 5.7 and trying to load a dump file into a database.
I created a empty database using CREATE TABLE database name.
That worked.
I exported a dump file from GoDaddy.
I used LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename' INTO TABLE database name;
I got and error no database selected.
I used: use database name;
Again entered LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename' INTO TABLE database name;
Got error Table database name. database name doesn't exist.
The dump file is in
C:\ and C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin
So I tried LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin/filename' INTO TABLE database name;
Same error, Any Ideas???

I created a empty database using CREATE TABLE database name. You confuse the terms DATABASE and TABLE. I used LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename' INTO TABLE database name; Dump file is a set of SQL statements which must be executed via any client, whereas LOAD DATA loads only the table data from CSV file. Any Ideas??? Study Reference Manual carefully.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reloading-sql-format-dumps.html

Thank you, that worked. - -  Just wondered why the other syntax didn't. Is it a windows 10i issue?
